# Hibernate ID generator "increment" by using annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

As per the Hibernate Developer guide 3.3 [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator), Hibernate provides support in many ways for generating Identifiers. But this is by using **XML based mapping**. [1] How to do the same by using Annotations? 

Especially I'm interested in 'increment' type. The closest thing that i found is using `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`. But this is a JPA based strategy.
 How can I use Hibernate based using Annotations? 
And Even this information is not present in the Hibernate Developer Guide of version 4.3! Any particular reason for this?

**UPDATE**
I'm very well aware of the four strategies which is from JPA. I'm interested in the other types which Hibernate provides. Like `hilo`, `increment`, and so on. In documentation this is done by using XML configurations.Is there any way to use it with Annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate implements JPA and uses the JPA id generation strategy.

Check the documentation here for 4.3 :
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/ : Section5.1.2.2. Identifier generator

Hibernate also provides [@GenericGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html) which can be used to configure Hibernate specific generator by passing in strategy attribute

Comment: I'm quoting from the hibernate Dev Guide "These are the four standard JPA generators. Hibernate goes beyond that and provide additional generators or additional options as we will see below". And below it talks about Other types of generators which hibernate provides. [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e2614) My question is about this!

Comment: Can you check if GenericGenerator annotation works for you. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html

Comment: GenericGenerator annotation works like a charm! That is what i was looking for! Thanks mate! Kindly update your Answer.

Answer (score 2):

For `Hibernate 4.x` you can find 4 types of `Generation Types`

> GeneratorType.AUTO - This is the default strategy and is portable across
>   different databases. Hibernate chooses the appropriate ID based on the
>   database.
>
> GeneratorType.IDENTITY - This setting is based on the identity provided
>   by some databases; it is the respon‐ sibility of the database to
>   provide a unique identifier.
>
> GeneratorType.SEQUENCE - 
>   Some databases provide a mechanism of sequenced numbers, so this setting will let
>   Hibernate use the sequence number.
>
> GeneratorType.TABLE -
>   Sometimes the primary keys have been created from a unique column in another
>   table. In this case, use the TABLE generator.

With the `Annotations:`

If the ID Generation Strategy is `NOT SET` it means you are using the `AUTO Strategy`.

To use the others, annotate like:

```
@Entity(name = "TBL_EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
@Id
@Column(name="ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int employeeId =0;
...
}
```

or

```
public class Employee {
@Id
@Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
@GeneratedValue (strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="empSeqGen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "empSeqGen", sequenceName = "EMP_SEQ_GEN")
private int employeeId =0;
...
 }
```

or

```
public class Employee {
@Id
@Column(name="ID")
@GeneratedValue (strategy= GenerationType.TABLE, generator="empTableGen")
@TableGenerator(name = "empTableGen", table = "EMP_ID_TABLE")
private int empoyeeId =0;
...
}
```

You can also use `Composite Identifiers`, in this case I recommend you go for the Book `Just Hibernate`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
private int id;
```